# how to change the nest array object key and same array in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays of an object `obj` and `editObj` I am trying the change the inner array key value from `obj` array-based on `editObj`.

```
const obj= [
   {
      "id":"cmate",
      "permissions":[
        {
            "name":"audioFeature",
            "description":"sample description",
            "options":[{"name":"Yes","value":"Y"}, {"name":"No","value":"N"}, {"name":"Veiw","value":"V"}],
         },
         {
            "name":"documentFeature",
            "description":"sample description",
            "options":[{"name":"Yes","value":"Y"},{"name":"No","value":"N"}],
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"Vmate",
      "permissions":[
         {
            "name":"audioFeature",
            "description":"sample description",
            "options":[{ "name":"Yes", "value":"Y"},{"name":"No", "value":"N"}],
         },
         {
            "name":"videoFeature",
            "description":"sample description",
            "options":[{ "name":"Yes", "value":"Y"},{"name":"No","value":"N"}],
         }
      ]
   }
] ;
const editObj = [
   {
      "id":"cmate",
      "attributes":[
         {
            "name":"audioFeature",
            "value":["Y",N"],
            "disabled":true
         },
         {
            "name":"documentFeature",
            "value":["N"],
            "disabled":false
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"Vmate",
      "attributes":[
         {
            "name":"audioFeature",
            "value":["Y","N"],
            "disabled":false
         },
         {
            "name":"videoFeature",
            "value":["Y","N"],
            "disabled":true
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I had tried with this code but I stuck in a certain time I try to return the `resultArr` but it's not working for me.

```
obj.map(el => {
        editObj.map(elm => {
          if (el.applicationId === elm.applicationId) {
            el.permissions.map(p => {
              elm.attributes.map(a => {
                if(p.name === a.name) {
                  console.log(el)
                  const resultArr = el.permissions.map((item, index) => {
                    let res = { ... item };
                    res.options = item.options.filter(option => elm[0].attributes[index].value.includes(option.value));
                    return res;
                  });
                  console.log(resultArr)
                }
              })
            })
          }
        })
      })
```

my expected output should be

```
[
   {
      "id":"cmate",
      "permissions":[
        {
            "name":"audioFeature",
            "description":"sample description",
            "options":[{"name":"Yes","value":"Y"}, {"name":"No","value":"N"}],
            "disabled":true
         },
         {
            "name":"documentFeature",
            "description":"sample description",
            "options":[{"name":"No","value":"N"}],
            "disabled":false
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"Vmate",
      "permissions":[
         {
            "name":"audioFeature",
            "description":"sample description",
            "options":[{ "name":"Yes", "value":"Y"},{"name":"No", "value":"N"}],
            "disabled":false
         },
         {
            "name":"videoFeature",
            "description":"sample description",
            "options":[{ "name":"Yes", "value":"Y"},{"name":"No","value":"N"}],
            "disabled":true
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece of code, it will take obj and editObj and return the output in outputObj.

```
const outputObj = [];
obj.forEach(el => {
    editObj.forEach(elm => {
        if (el.id === elm.id) {
            let tempObj = {
                id: el.id,
                permissions:[]
            }
            el.permissions.forEach(p => {
                elm.attributes.forEach(a => {
                    if (p.name === a.name) {
                        const rObj = {
                            name: p.name,
                            description: p.description,
                            disabled: a.disabled,
                            options: p.options.filter(option => { 
                                         if(a.value.includes(option.value))  { 
                                               return option 
                                         } 
                                      })
                             }
                              tempObj.permissions.push(rObj)
                     }
                })
            })
            outputObj.push(tempObj);
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little bit and it start showing something:

You need to explicitly return from arrow function.

```
console.log(obj.map(el => {
        return editObj.map(elm => {
          if (el.id === elm.id) {
            return el.permissions.map(p => {
               return elm.attributes.map(a => {
                if(p.name === a.name) {
                     return resultArr = el.permissions.map((item, index) => {
                        let res = { ... item };
                        res.options = item.options.filter(option => elm.attributes[index].value.includes(option.value));
                        return res;
                  });
                }
              })
            })
          }
        })
      }));
```

Checkout an interesting article to understand your mistake:
[https://dev.to/samanthaming/es6-arrow-functions-cheatsheet-1cn#:~:text=With%20normal%20functions%2C%20if%20you,return%20keyword%20can%20be%20skipped](https://dev.to/samanthaming/es6-arrow-functions-cheatsheet-1cn#:%7E:text=With%20normal%20functions%2C%20if%20you,return%20keyword%20can%20be%20skipped).